# Fortran Module Wrapping in Python using ctypes

Tags: memory-management, fortran, ctypes, f2py, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to wrap some Fortran modules to be called from Python using the ctypes library. I am going directly from Fortran to Python without writing any C code. Simply compiling a shared library.

Yet I am struggling with what the best approach should be for memory allocation, namely who should own the data. Should I allocate inside the Fortran module and then expose the data using ctypes or should I allocate with numpy and pass as argument to Fortran.

I am also open to doing the intermediary step and write the C wrappers (F->C->Python). But then the same question arises.
Thanks!

**PS: I know F2Py exists I know how to use it but I am interested in going the ctypes way.**

**mod.f90:**

```
module angio_global

    use iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    integer  :: lx,ly
    real*8 :: raio_init

    real*8,allocatable :: phi(:,:)
    real*8 :: epsilon,rho_phi


contains

    subroutine init_fields(phi_,lx_,ly_)
        integer ,intent(in) :: lx_,ly_
        real*8,intent(in) :: phi_(lx_,ly_)
        integer :: i,j
        real*8 :: dx,dy
        lx = lx_
        ly = ly_
        allocate(phi(0:lx+1,0:ly+1))
        phi(1:lx,1:ly) = phi_
        raio_init = 20.0_dp
        epsilon = 1.0_dp
        rho_phi = 1.0_dp
        do j=1,ly
            do i=1,lx
                dx = i-lx/2.0_dp
                dy = j-ly/2.0_dp
                if(dx**2+dy**2<raio_init**2) phi(i,j) = 1.0_dp
            enddo
        enddo
    end subroutine

    subroutine wrap_init_fields(phi_,lx_,ly_) bind(c)
        integer(c_int),intent(in),value :: lx_,ly_
        real(c_double),intent(in) :: phi_(lx_,ly_)
        call init_fields(phi_,lx_,ly_)
    end subroutine

    subroutine wrap_get_phi(phi_,lx_,ly_) bind(c)
        integer(c_int),intent(in),value :: lx_,ly_
        real(c_double),intent(inout) :: phi_(lx_,ly_)
        phi_ = phi(1:lx,1:ly)
    end subroutine
end module
```

**caller.py:**

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int, c_double,c_float
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
angio = CDLL('./global.so')

def init_fields(phi):
    Nx,Ny = np.shape(phi)
    phi_ptr = ndpointer(dtype=phi.dtype,shape=phi.shape,flags="F_CONTIGUOUS")
    angio.wrap_init_fields.argtypes = [phi_ptr,c_int,c_int]
    angio.wrap_init_fields(phi,Nx,Ny)
    return

def get_phi(phi):
    Nx,Ny = np.shape(phi)
    phi_ptr = ndpointer(dtype=phi.dtype,shape=phi.shape,flags="F_CONTIGUOUS")
    angio.wrap_get_phi.argtypes = [phi_ptr,c_int,c_int]
    angio.wrap_get_phi(phi,Nx,Ny)

phi = np.zeros((200,200),dtype = np.float64,order="F")-1.0
init_fields(phi)
```

Comment: Be aware that the "best" could be quite opinion based. It is good to show some code that illustrates how you actually used the data. As a rule, global data is normally bad thing. Module data is also global in some sense.

Comment: @VladimirF Added some code :) By best I mean performance and safety-wise

Comment: I do not see any issues with performance or safety here. It is a really design choice. Global data is usually an anti-pattern. Regarding the performance - you have the code, you have to measure the performance.

Comment: "allocate with numpy and pass as argument to Fortran" will be likely easier and cleaner than "allocating inside Fortran and passing the allocation to Python". That said, Fortran 2018 adds interoperability of Fortran allocations between C and Fortran and several compilers have it already implemented, like `ifort`.